# How can I programmatically configure Spring's @Configuration annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

Specifically, I would like to be able share configuration classes by instantiating them and including them. Where you would normally do this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({SharedConfiguration.class})
public class MyAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  //stuff
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class SharedConfiguration {
  //stuff
}
```

I would like to do this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  public SharedConfiguration sharedConfig(){
    return new SharedConfiguration("com.example");
  }

  //stuff
}

@Configuration
public class SharedConfiguration {
  public SharedConfiguration(String package){
    //tell Spring to scan package
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that I need to be able to tell the shared component doing the scan what package to look at. It will different depending on what project it is being used in.

EDIT:

To provide some additional context, I'm trying to make a general-use configuration for setting up Hibernate and EHCache using our external configuration provider that several projects can use. I'm certainly open to other methods to doing this, but this seemed like the most logical path to me. I'm sure there's ~something~ in Spring that I can fiddle with to say, "Here! Scan this path when Spring initializes you!" instead of hard-coding it into an annotation.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem; more detail would be helpful. In particular, what's the purpose for scanning different packages under different circumstances? This sounds like a case for profiles, conditionals, and/or autoconfiguration.

Comment: @chrylis Updated the question to make it a bit more clear. It certainly may be an XY problem, I'm trying to do things in a programmatic way and Spring is decidedly not very programmatic.

Comment: You're exactly wanting autoconfiguration. It basically uses SPI to find `@Configuration` classes and then imports them into the context.

Comment: Well, the issue is the value in the @ComponentScan annotation. Even with autoconfig or profiles, that value is still hardcoded. I don't want to have to force every single project to use the same package names for their model classes.

Comment: Ah, I see. If all you're wanting to do is make the JPA base package configurable, if you can use Spring Boot, the client package would just need to specify `@EntityScan("com.foo.app1.domain")` in its configuration.

Comment: if you don't want autoconfiguration, why not manual configuration, create/configure bean manually, then autowire them as needed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that isn't possible with all Spring features. Even if it were, the problem remains: how do I give my configuration class programmable parameters? All of the suggestions given only work if I'm using default Spring providers, and I can't use them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of property sources in this case.
In the test case, I am setting a system property that is picked up by the Spring property source configuration -

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyAppContextTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        // use a system property to configure the component scan location of the SharedConfiguration
        // where the "ExampleBean" lives
        System.setProperty("packages", "net.savantly.other.packages");
    }

    @Test
    public void ensureExampleBeanExists() {
        // throws exception if it doesnt exist
        context.getBean(ExampleBean.class);
    }


    @Configuration
    @Import(MyAppContext.class)
    static class TestContext {

    }
}
```

Using the Spring expression language in the ComponentScan -

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("${packages}")
public class SharedConfiguration {}
```

Other Referenced Classes -

```
@Configuration
@Import(SharedConfiguration.class)
public class MyAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    SharedConfiguration sharedConfig;

  //stuff
}

@Service
public class ExampleBean {

}
```